# html form attribute target=_blank still sets window.opener in new window

Tags: html, forms, security

**Expected behavior:** [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target), an html form element with `target="_blank"` and `action="https://www.whatever.com"` should open `whatever.com` in a new window/tab where the value of `window.opener` should be `null`.

**Observed behavior:** The new window's `window.opener` is non-null. Instead it is a reference to the parent window.

[Here is a simple code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-pond-kn15k). Click the submit button and then open browser devtools in the new window to test the value of `window.opener`. The sandboxed html includes a link as well, to show that `anchor` tag with `target="_blank"` is behaving as expected.

I have also tried being extra-explicit, adding `rel="noopener"` to the `form`, and adding `formtarget="_blank" rel="noopener"` to the submit input.

On my machine, I have a more complex setup where I am POSTing the form to a simple server. Still seeing same results.

I am observing this behavior in

- Chrome v96.0.4664.55
- Firefox v94.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Not supported anywhere except preview version of safari.

[safari](https://webkit.org/blog/12040/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-135/)

[chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=931209)

[firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1509346)